# why is streaming to an flv server with ffmpeg only showing black/blank video for clients?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

When I stream to an flv server, like flash media server, using ffmpeg, like

```
 ffmpeg -i input -vcodec libx264 rtmp://hostname/streamname
```

it turns out black. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that in "more recent" versions of ffmpeg, the default x264 pixel format is "yuv422p" which isn't supported by [most commercial encoders](http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/default-to-yuv-td4652987.html).

Fix: specify -pix_fmt yuv420p or  -pix_fmt yuyv422 for the x264 format.